# Kibana Rounding Timestamp to nearest custom Window

Tags: timestamp, rounding, kibana

In the Kibana Search bar, I am able to filter data based on the timestamps -- `timestamp:[now-5h/h TO now]`

But Kibana is not allowing to do as follows `timestamp:[now-5h/2h TO now]`
As I am aggregating the data according to the custom window of 2 hours, I want to see the last 5 hours data with nearest to 2 hours. Can you please help me with this?